# How to check if there is a record change in .net core 2.1 mvc

Tags: asp.net-core

Just after

```
_context.Update(model);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

how can I check if there is really a change of record other than comparing original fields with the new one? it is going to be bulky to check one by one specially with multiple model and many fields.

Comment: A look [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-2.1) may help to see what the return values of a method mean ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SaveChanges()` and `await SaveChangesAsync()` returns an int value which is the number of affected records if the Add/Update/Delete operation was done successfuly. So, just catch the returned value and check if it is > 0.

```
_context.Update(model);
var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;    

if(success)
 // operation done successfuly
else
// operation failed
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  but `var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` is returning 1 even if i didn't make any updates,  i think it is checking if it is executed successfully, not whether there is a change of values (i'm working on the Edit controller btw)